# Multiple definition of namespace::variable even using ifndef

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, ifndef

I know I must be doing something wrong here.

rank.h

```
#ifndef RANK_H
#define RANK_H
namespace mmi {
int chunk;
void rank(int my_rank);
}
#endif
```

rank.cpp

```
#include "rank.h"
namespace mmi {
//do something with chunk
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "rank.h"
int main() {
    mmi::chunk = 1;
}
```

And the output of compilation;

```
g++ -g -Wall -std=gnu++11   -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -std=gnu++11   -c -o rank.o rank.cpp
mpic++ main.o rank.o  -o main
rank.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `mmi::chunk'
main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

My understanding is that header file is being included multiple times. But I was expecting to correct this issue by using the `#ifndef`.

So, may I ask what's going on here?

Comment: "even using ifndef...". Include guards have absolutely no relation to program-wide multiple definition problems.There's no "even" here. `ifndef` has nothing to do with it and can't help you in any way, shape of form. Just don't define non-inline variables in header files.

Comment: the `ifndef`, an [Include Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), prevents multiple inclusions within one [Translation Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). You have two translation units, one for each compiled file, each including rank.h exactly once. The problem comes when the linker assembles the two into a single program and finds `chunk` in each compiled object. The linker doesn't try to figure out which is the real `chunk`, because they both are, and gives up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
int chunk;
```

is not only a declaration, it is also a definition. Every .cpp file that `#include`s the .hpp file ends up defining it.

Change it to

```
extern int chunk;
```

Then, make sure to define it in a .cpp file.

rank.cpp

```
#include "rank.h"
namespace mmi {
   int chunk;
  //do something with chunk
}
```

Comment: Another option, since C++14, is `inline int chunk;` in the header

Comment: W00t! There goes a bunch of boiler plate. Now all I have to do is talk the boss into letting me use a modern compiler.

Comment: @M.M, I  have not been able to catch up with C++14. How's that different from using `inline` for global variables?

Comment: @RSahu this is a global variable

Comment: Why would your boss force you into using an old compiler in the first place @user4581301? Knowing that the updated version probably has thousands of bug fixes

Comment: @HackerDaGreat57 but all those bugs are known and will have been taken into account in the existing software or were never encountered at all. Migrating to the new compiler is an unnecessary risk, could be new bugs or break code counting on a now-fixed bug, and the project manager will likely be gone before migration to new tools is forced by changing circumstances. The smart move is to spend a bit of money to keep the products and and tool chains up to date, but humans, being what they are, will almost always kick the problem down the road for more money or easier living now.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ each file (aka translation unit) is compiled **separately**. So the compilation of main.cpp is completely independent from the compilation of rank.cpp. There is no way that a #define in one compilation can affect the other compilation. And by the time you link your two object files together the defines have disappeared.

The purpose of *include guards* is to prevent the inclusion of one header file twice during a single compilation, not across multiple compilations.